# Какие новые проекты по JS взять для практики?

Tags: javascript

пару недель назад мне посоветовали здесь использовать практику для изучения javascript'a. Получилось отлично , сделал свой To-do List на чистом JS потом с применением React'a. Но где я могу найти другие задачи ( желательно с + Redux) .

```
Я посмотрел в Google но там из советов - это обычные TO-DO
```

Откуда можно брать действительно практические задачи и выполнять. Задачи по JS тоже интересны, особенно связанны с алгоритмами, но хочется именно работать в связке с вебом.
Заранее спасибо, знаю что тут отзывчивые люди которые посоветуют правильные задачи , которые я встречу на реальных проектов.

Comment: Берите любую браузерную игру, попробуйте повторить её механику на JS )

Comment: Реальные задачи скукатищя, интересные задачи требуют время, а время - деньги. Бизнес не любит тратить он любит зарабатывать. Так что берите привычку искать интересное даже в серых буднях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скажу от себя. Противникам можно добавить свой ответ.

Реальное - это интересное до поры. Интерес он увядает со временем. Реальность жестока. Совет - любите свое дело иначе со временем ничем вас не завлечь, ни привлечь, не удержать и т.д. Не ищите реальные задачи. Это же девелопмент - строительство. Что там может быть в реальности интересного? Самому построить "Бурдж-Хали́фа". Думаете это реально? В реальности будите в основном каким-нибудь "моляром либо каменьщиком либо сварщиком ... со временем мастером и прорабом" и строить очередную многоэтажку (ширпотреб) для ипотеки вот оно какое строительство пусть и с якобы современным дизайном и компонентным подходом в функциональном стиле. Любите свое дело, а чем заняться  всегда найдется.